# How to put a given number at the same position of all occurrences of a another number of an array in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to put a given number at the same position of all occurrences of a another number of an array in another array.

To understand what I am saying I made a simple function which does what I want and I am showing you the execution. But

My question is: Is there a command in a module like numpy that already does that ?

## Function

```
def swap(tab1,tab2):
    n, m = tab1.shape
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if tab1[i,j]==1.:
                tab2[i,j]=2.
    return tab2
```

## Execution

```
tab1 = np.array([[0,1.,0],[1.,1.,1.],[0,1.,0]])
tab2 = np.array([[1.,1.,0],[1.,0.,1.],[0,1.,1.]])

tab1

array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])

tab2

array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.]])

saw(tab1,tab2)

array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: how come result has 2 at position [1,1] ?

Comment: I changed my question sorry, not well explained. I want a module that does what my function does. I know it's weird.

Comment: your question is very confusing. if tab1 has 1 at [1,1] position and tab2 has 0 at [1,1] position then how result has 2 at the same position ?

Comment: @JayParikh because the index [1, 1] contained the value 1 in `tab1`, he has replaced its value in `tab2`, with a value 2. His question is asking how to get the indices of each occurrence of a value in a numpy array, and update the values at those same indices in a second numpy array.

Comment: I know my question is very confusing but my function is very clear :  it puts a 2. in tab2 every time there is a 1. in tab1. So if there is a 1. at [1,1] in tab1 then there is a 2. at [1,1] in tab2. Sorry @Jay Parikh my question is not well formulated but at least Tom Wyllie understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is pretty good at this sort of thing. You can use `np.where` and fancy indexing as follows;

```
tab2[np.where(tab1==1.)] = 2.
```

---

Demonstration:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> tab1 = np.array([[0,1.,0],[1.,1.,1.],[0,1.,0]])
>>> tab2 = np.array([[1.,1.,0],[1.,0.,1.],[0,1.,1.]])
>>> tab2[np.where(tab1==1.)] = 2.0
>>> tab2
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.]])
```